# Work out the percentage of the day that has elapsed

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

Slightly strange question, but hopefully someone can help.

In essence, if the time was 12pm the the elapsed percentage would be 50%, 6am would be 25% and 16pm would be 75%.

Given the current time, how could you work out the amount of day that already passed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you can get the current time of day, it'd be pretty easy to calculate the percentage of the day elapsed.

```
percentage = (hours / 24 + minutes / (60 * 24)) * 100
```

Comment: one too many parentheses there... the first one could be removed.

Comment: In some countries, this misses by [an hour twice a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and [an additional second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) sometimes

Answer (score 4):

24hours are 100%
so 24/currentTime = result
100 / result = % ;)

Answer (score 3):

gettimeofday(true) returns the number of seconds elapsed since midnight as a float (I think), so you want: `gettimeofday(true)/(60*60*24)`. Multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

**EDIT:** Actually, gettimeofday returns the number of seconds elapsed since the start of the epoch, so you need to subtract midnight:

```
$midnight = strtotime('00:00');
$epochseconds = gettimeofday(true);
$timeofdayseconds = $epochseconds - $midnight;
$timepercent = $timeofdayseconds/(60*60*24)*100;
```

Comment: Note, this works most of the time EXCEPT on DST days! Today my clock went back one hour and this function fails as the number of hours from sunday midnight and sunday 8pm have an extra +1 hour! Be warned

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer bugs me for many reasons including the relationship to a real life calendar. Personally, I would probably do this:

```
<?php
$start = strtotime("today");
$end = strtotime("tomorrow");
$now = time();
$secondstoday = $end - $start;
$secondselapsed = $now - $start;
$percentage = ($secondselapsed / $secondstoday ) * 100;

printf('%.2f%% of the day has passed (%d out of %d seconds)', $percentage, $secondselapsed, $secondstoday);
```

result:

```
72.22% of the day has passed (62402 out of 86400 seconds)
```

You could then extend it even further by making a function and changing the range from `"today"` and `"tomorrow"` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know php but is there any way to get the current date witch i guess :P can you extract the hours out of this or minutes how exact do you want it to be?, Current hours/24 * 100 :P
current minutes/1440 * 100