# How to get seconds elapsed since midnight

Tags: php

Using PHP how do you get the number of seconds elapsed since midnight of the current day?

All i've tried right now is:

```
$hour=substr(date("h:i:s"),0,2);
$minute=substr(date("h:i:s"),3,2);
echo $hour."\r\n";
echo $minute."\r\n";
```

...but it doesn't return the correct server time of the response and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck on this? What have you tried?

Comment: All i've tried right now is            $hour=substr(date("h:i:s"),0,2);
$minute=substr(date("h:i:s"),3,2);
echo $hour."\r\n";
echo $minute."\r\n";           but it doesn't return the correct server time of the response and i don't know how to do that. I'm using a GET request elsewhere and I'm trying to get my php script to return the number of seconds elapsed since midnight of the current day

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/479147

Comment: Also, in what timezone? Note that the PHP webserver's timezone is not always the same as your visitor's

Comment: Look into time -> http://php.net/time

Comment: It doesn't matter about timezone just as long as the result is generated from the server timestamp in the response

Comment: Please let this be the very last question ever asked on this topic. This question and most questions like it can be answered by reviewing the manual. For relative formats, please see the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php More details on acceptable date formats can be found in the manual here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: @Nubcake: I apologize for being rude with my last comment/answer.  But I'd ask that next time you first use the search feature on this website to find any posts similar to or exactly matching your problem.

Answer (score 32):

This should work.

```
echo time() - strtotime("today");
```

This will only show your servers timezone though.

Answer (score 26):

Simplest I believe would be dividing the current time (in seconds) by the number of seconds in a day (60*60*24) and taking the remainder:

```
(time() % 86400)
```

Comment: Nice, but it counts seconds since midnight *UTC*, not local time

Comment: True it uses Linux epoch in GMT/UTC -- Guess it's never been a problem for me since I use UTC for everything anyways.

Comment: "I'll be home around midnight honey" *loud chattering on the other end*, "No honey, I uh, meant midnight *UTC*!" ;)

Comment: OK,.. everything PHP wise :)

Comment: isn't current time in seconds already total seconds from midnight?

Comment: time() returns correct Unix time in seconds, this is the most concise method I know of.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using DateTime:

```
 $timeDiff = $time->diff(new \DateTime("today")); 
 $timeDiffSec = $timeDiff->h* 3600 + $timeDiff->i*60 + $timeDiff->s;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo (date('G') * 3600 + date('i') * 60);
```

Multiply the current hour by the number of seconds in each hour and add it to the number of minutes multiplied by the number of seconds in each minute.

Comment: But that rounds it down to the nearest minute.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to get time from start of the day to current hours and seconds of the day, this can be done like this, you will still need to set your timezone time in place of 'Asia/Karachi'. This gets correct time since midnight in user's timezone instead of server's timezone time.

Here is working link:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/ykJC2R

```
//Get current time timestamp
$time_now = time();

//Create DateTime class object
$date = new DateTime(); 

//Set timestamp to DateTime object
$date->setTimestamp( $time_now );

//Set timezone so that code don't get server's timezone midnight time
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi'));

//Print current time in user's timezone
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "<br />";

//Get time stamp for midnight tonight
$date->modify('today midnight');
$midnight_time = $date->getTimestamp();

//Print midnight time in user's timezone
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "<br />"; 

    //Now you will need to subtract midnight time from current time in user's timezone
$seconds_since_midnight = $time_now - $midnight_time;

//Print seconds since midnight in your timezone
echo $seconds_since_midnight;
```

Answer (score 3):

The shortest solution would probably be this:

```
$time = "12:34:56";
echo strtotime("{$time}UTC", 0);
```

The reason this works is that `strtotime` uses the second parameter to determine the *date* part of the time string. In this case, I'm using `0`, which means the full string results in `1970-01-01 12:34:56 UTC`. `strtotime` then returns the UNIX timestamp (the number of seconds elapsed since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`). Note: the first parameter has `UTC` appended to prevent the time being interpreted as local.

#### DateTime (with microseconds)

A faster (3×) and more precise alternative to the already mentioned `DateTime::diff` solution:

```php
$date = new DateTime;
[$h, $m, $s] = explode(':', $date->format('H:i:s.u'));
echo $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, if you are receiving the time as a string and want to calculate the number of seconds from that time:

```
$time = strtotime($_GET['time']); // Do some verification before this step
$midnight = strtotime("00:00"); // Midnight measured in seconds since Unix Epoch
$sinceMidnight = $time - $midnight; // Seconds since midnight
```

There you go. Read into [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function of PHP and [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: How would that work with a time from a response such as 01:28:49 ? Do i substitute 00:00 with the server time?

Comment: No. 00:00 is midnight, and then you subtract the current time to get the time since midnight in seconds. Is that your question?

Comment: Let me try to explain it simpler sorry , I'm using a GET request and in that response from the server you'll get the Date: section so say if the time (from that section) is 01:35:33 , how do you calculate the number of seconds elapsed since midnight from that time , I forgot to add that in the OP.

Comment: I made some changes based on what I think you're saying. Read into strtotime(), I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow , it's very late here , Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

In Carbon, the number of seconds elapsed since midnight can be found like this:

`$seconds_since_midnight = $dt->secondsSinceMidnight()`;

And though there's no minutes since midnight I suppose you do:

`$minutes_since_midnight = (int) floor($dt->secondsSinceMidnight()/60);`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo time() - strtotime('today');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm keeping the rule that operations on numbers are always faster than operations on strings. When the numbers are integers, operations are even faster (because CPU registers are always "integer wide", means have 32-bit or 64-bit and all other non-floating point types are converted to integer before any operation is performed).

Anyway, I found such solution to count seconds till midnight with timezone include:

`$tillmidnight = 86400 - (time() - mktime(0, 0, 0));`

You wanted to get seconds elapsed since midnight so:

`$sincemidnight = time() - mktime(0, 0, 0);`

It is good to review your php.ini also and set your time zone (date.timezone under [Date] section) there. If you do not have access to php.ini, you can set your time zone in PHP code using date_default_timezone_set(); function.

Comment: I can't see how this works. It doesn't take timezone into account whatsoever.

Comment: @BerenddeBoer it takes timezone from what you've configured yourself. That's why I love this solution, noone decide by you here.
Timezone for runtime is set by date_default_timezone_set();
Timezone for single PHP environment (note, that there can be many on your server, depends on what you need) is set in php.ini and taken from there for every code running under this environment.

Answer (score -2):

I know this post is pretty old now, but people will still find it, like I did.

There's a few of important things to note.

-Firstly, no need to substr the output of date(), just only ask for the part you actually need.

-Secondly, don't default the time() value in subsequent instructions. While it may work 99.999% of the time, if the clock ticks between the instructions it can generate chaotic results with the new time() value.

-Finally, use capital "H"; lower case "h" returns 12-hour clock values.

```
$time_now=time();
$hour=date('H', $time_now);
$minute=date("i", $time_now);
echo $hour, PHP_EOL;
echo $minute, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: The question was "How to get seconds elapsed since midnight"  so , returning hours and minutes is not an answer (sorry!)