# How to get time only timestamp from a date in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a time field in a PHP that receives Hours and minutes (H:i).
This goes into a `\Datetime Object`. 
By magic and, in my case, undesiredly, the current Date is added to that time.

**I would like to strip the date and keep the time only.**

```
 $timeonly = $this->getDate()->format('H:i');
```

This gives me the string 10:00.

But now ... how can this string be converted into the desired integer `36000` which is 10h?

I tried `strtotime($timeonly)` but this added the date again...

Is this even a good idea, and do I not find it because it's so trivial or because this isn't done?

Maybe there's something in `DateTime->` like `returnTimeWithoutDate`?

Comment: [Something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462894/how-to-get-seconds-elapsed-since-midnight) - potential duplicate as *technically* you're only interested in the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight on the given day (if I understand the question correctly).

Comment: PS I even tried stuff like

 print_r(strtotime($date->setDate(1970,1,0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

(Trying to reset the date to 0... probably not worth anything)

Comment: I'm not used to such quick answers.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial with a little bit of math:

```
function timeToSeconds(\DateTime $dt)
{
    return $dt->format('H') * 3600 + $dt->format('i') * 60;
}

echo timeToSeconds($this->getDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Hack the code :

```
$timeonly = $this->getDate()->format('H')*3600 + $this->getDate()->format('i')*60;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try sometings like this :

```
$timeonly = $this->getDate()->format('H:i');
$date = strtotime($timeonly);
echo date('H', $date);
```