# How to get milliseconds elapsed since midnight in PHP?

Tags: php, date, math

much like this question [How to get seconds elapsed since midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462894/how-to-get-seconds-elapsed-since-midnight) but i need millisecond-precision instead of second-precision, and not sure how to go about it, help?

Comment: Does PHP timestamp return millisecond? Or it's not? As far as I know it's using ms

Comment: why not just `seconds * 1000` since you found how to get seconds?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do it is `echo round(microtime(true) * 1000) % 86400000;`. First you get the unix microtime (microseconds). Then turn that into milliseconds. Modulo the amount of milliseconds in a day and take the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`microtime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

```
echo microtime(true);
```

gives me (yours will obviously differ).

```
1550546796.3718
```

You get your millisecond precision there. Then you can subtract from the seconds till 12:00:00 AM today. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
echo microtime(true) - mktime(0,0,0,date('m', time()), date('d', time()), date('Y', time()));
```